# Opportunities in quantum computing for an undergrad

Tags: resource-request

I am currently an undergrad student in computer engineering in Brazil and I have taken the Quantum mechanics subject as well as I am did a [project](https://github.com/Danielgb23/ic_comp_quantica) (the two jupyter notebooks, it's in portuguese though) on quantum computing with a teacher that is currently building one at my college. Apart from the chances I already have of learning about this subject are there other means or opportunities any of you recommend going after?

Comment: This question has been asked before. See : https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/resources-for-learning-quantum-computing-from-an-undergraduate-physics-perspecti , https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/are-there-any-organised-resources-available-from-where-i-can-begin-my-quantum-co?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for career advice. Nevertheless, try contacting researchers working on the subject if you're interested in research.