# How do I (MSc in quantum physics) start acquiring quantum programming/simulation skills?

Tags: resource-request

I have finished my Masters in quantum physics, but have always omitted all this programming stuff within my studies.

Now, looking for jobs, I realize that this was a mistake since most of the jobs require some form of computer-based quantum physics.

I want to teach myself how to do this. I think the best way would be to have an application-focused course or something like that.

Just reading through theoretical frameworks and how in general simulations go is not the way to go here, I think, ideally, I would have some step-by-step application-focused course or something like that and look up the necessary theoretical framework on the way?

I already have had some minor courses on qiskit, but I lack of actual problems/real-life applications/tasks that guide me on how to do quantum programming in real life. Knowing how to write a qbit in qiskit is nice, but I need to learn how to follow a path guiding me to successfully apply quantum simulations in a work environment.

Do you have recommendations on how I can start/is there something online?

Comment: possible duplicate of one of: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5234, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1367/55, and links therein

Answer (score 0):

My background was BSc in physics and MSc in pure mathematics prior to studying quantum computing, so I will share some resources that helped me make the transition.

If you have little or no experience programming, then the place to start is with the famous "4 hours of Python" video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw. After this, you will know enough programming to work through the IBM Quantum Learning series here https://learning.quantum.ibm.com/catalog/courses. That will give you a good idea of what quantum computing is all about, and you can fill in any knowledge gaps with the standard text from Nielsen and Chuang [https://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Computation-Information-10th-Anniversary/dp/1107002176](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107002176).

With this knowledge base (and your MSc in physics), you can start reaching out to researchers or apply for internships/jobs in your specific area of interest. If you are specifically interested in real-life applications, then the internship/job route is the best way to acquire this knowledge. If you don't get any responses immediately, then add Qiskit projects to your GitHub until you inevitably become an attractive candidate.