How to learn mathematics and physics for quantum computing
I am currently pursuing my bachelor's in computer science (AI). I am very passionate and curious about quantum technologies, particularly quantum information theory, and quantum computing, and I want to pursue higher education in this field.
I started reading the book Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by "M.A Nielsen and I.L Chuang". But could not understand anything in it. I realised I lacked both mathematics and physics required for understanding it.
I want to know how can I learn maths and physics for understanding Quantum Computing and Quantum information theory? Is it helpful if I learn these both in depth first and then go for quantum computing?

From the mathematics side you only need linear algebra and basic probability theory to get started. NB: you can study quantum info/computing without any physics.

does https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1367 or https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5234/55 answer your question?
