# What is a good video resource for quantum computing?

Tags: resource-request

Can anyone refer me to a good video resource for quantum computing? I found this post helpful [Currently, what are the best structured courses available online on quantum computing?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2667/currently-what-are-the-best-structured-courses-available-online-on-quantum-comp), but Vazirani's youtube course has many videos deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artur Ekert is in the process of posting video lectures from his course in Oxford....
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkespgaZN4gmu0nWNmfMflVRqw0VPkCGH

Answer (score 2):

John Preskill posted his lectures from the first term of Quantum Computing course, [Ph/CS 219A Quantum Computation](http://theory.caltech.edu/%7Epreskill/ph219/ph219_2020-21.html), at CalTech here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0ojjrEqIyPy-1RRD8cTD_lF1hflo89Iu

Answer (score 2):

Ryan O'Donnell recorded a [semester](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78tSf2R1huk) of lectures (mostly on a chalkboard) at Carnegie Mellon.

Sevag Gharibian has an introductory course as well as an intermediate/advanced course from the Paderborn University [here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3WKNe_LK9JQkuinaLA_orQ); these I believe were recorded on his webcam for uploading to Paderborn's students initially and then to YouTube later.

Answer (score 1):

[Nathan Wiebe lectures](https://www.youtube.com/@nathanwiebe5305/videos) cover the more recent quantum algorithms such as QSVT and Qubitization in addition to the standard material.

Comment: Great! He quickly gets to topics just nearly outside my ken.