# Why can no pair of single qubits look like $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle$)?

Tags: entanglement, textbook-and-exercises

I've just started to learn Quantum Computing and, to do it, I'm reading the course "I[ntroduction from Quantum Computing](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/introduction/why-quantum-computing)" by IBM.

Now, I'm reading the chapter "[Entangled states](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/introduction/entangled-states)", section "[Entangled states](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/introduction/entangled-states#entangled-3-34)" where I have found the formula:

$$|\Phi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle).$$

They say about this state vector:

> There are no pairs of single qubit states $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$
> whose product state would look like this.

But I don't understand it. Why there are no pairs of single qubits? It is because both qubits are on state 0 and 1 at the same time, isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose there are two single qubit states $|a\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$ and $|b\rangle=\delta|0\rangle + \gamma|1\rangle$ such that their product state is that entangled state. Thus, the product state would look like:

$$
|a\rangle \otimes |b\rangle=\alpha\delta|00\rangle+\alpha\gamma|01\rangle+\beta\delta|10\rangle+\beta\gamma|11\rangle
$$

Since the state we want is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$, we have that $\alpha\delta=\beta\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\alpha\gamma=\beta\delta=0$. It is easy to see a contradiction here. Since $\alpha\gamma=0$, either one of the terms in this product must be equal to $0$. However, if either is zero, $\alpha\delta$ or $\beta\gamma$ will also be equal to $0$, but we want them to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Therefore, no such states $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ exist.

Answer (score 4):

The tensor product of two vectors $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}c \\ d \end{pmatrix}$ is $\begin{pmatrix} ac \\ ad \\ bc \\ bd \end{pmatrix}$. In this case, determining the inability to represent the state as a product of two qubit vectors is simpler than some others: $a$ and/or $d$ as well as $b$ and/or $c$ must be 0 for $ad$ and $bc$ to be 0, but *any* variable being 0 will make either $ac$ or $bd$ 0 as well, so there's no way the state vector of the $\left|\Phi\right>$ state can ever be written in the form $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} \otimes  \begin{pmatrix}c \\ d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} ac \\ ad \\ bc \\ bd \end{pmatrix}$.

$\left|00\right>$ by itself is $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, so $a$ and $c$ being 1 and $b$ and $d$ being 0 allows the tensor product, meaning it is not entangled.

Answer (score 3):

To put in simple words, there are basically two types of quantum states - separable and entangled. Separable states can be writen as a tensor product of other states while entangled states cannot.

The state you are asking about, so-called Bell state $|\beta_{00}\rangle$, is an example of entangled state, hence it cannot be writen as tensor product of two others states (mathematically it is explained in other answers).

*Disclaimer: My answer may seem oversimplifying. I am of course talking only about pure states and may be I neglected some details. However, for explanation to a beginner, I think the answer is sufficient and explain the issue asked about.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm going to ask you this because I want to do more courses about this: which course are you studying? I want to do it. Every course is good to learn more about this amazing subject. Thanks!

Comment: @VansFannel: More or less I study the subject on my own. Firstly, I went thought IBM Q manual, then I enrolled to on-line course on Coursera, followed by reading of countless articles. You can find a list of courses (including the one on Coursera I took) here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2667/currently-what-are-the-best-structured-courses-available-online-on-quantum-comp. Concerning a good introductory book, try this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.09415, something on Qiskit: https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.04359 and list of algorithms: https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03719