Beginners Guide to Quantum Computing
This might not be a relevant question here, but if I may, what are the resources you would recommend like books, online courses and yt channels I should start following up on?
Also the basics I would need, like LA, where should I learn this from that focuses on QC?
I have started with Qiskit by IBM as of yet and would like to dive deeper, also any programmes i could built to learn more about it.

did you have a look at https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request?tab=Votes? eg https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2667/55
